# I cant get the whole source code by webscraper - SIMPLE HTML DOM

Tags: php, simple-html-dom, scraper

here is the problem, im scraping images from site (phillips.cz). Images which i need are in slider.. if i am on page and click to view the whole source code, copy it into my page.html and scrape the source code from scraper.php the slider is there with images.

But when I use simple html dom - code

```html
<?php
//header("Content-type:text/plaintext");

//Importing classes
require_once("simple_html_dom.php");
require_once("ProjektX.php");

//Creating instance of crawler
$cr = new Crawler();

//Here i have ID of products which i edit d
$lines = file("basic.txt");
$lines = array_unique($lines);
$lines = array_values($lines);

//Here im editing them
foreach($lines as $a) 
$odkazy[] = "https://www.philips.cz" . trim($a);


//For testing im trying to get just one product of 2000
$odkazy = $cr->oddo(0,1,$odkazy);


foreach($odkazy as $a) {

 $html = new simple_html_dom();
 $html->load_file("https://www.philips.cz/c-p/7022331PH/stolni-svitidlo");

  
}
//Outputing the html source code
echo($html);

?>
```

It loads page BUT without the slider image.
So back to my question - Why does it take just source code without the slider?
And if you could direct me on the right path.
Here is URL where im trying to get that slider images - https://www.philips.cz/c-p/7022331PH/stolni-svitidlo

Comment: without looking at the website or the "slider" - my gues swould be the images are loaded dynamically with javascript so perhaps you would need a "headless" browser ~ phantom.js, casper.js??

Comment: Shit, u are right, they are dynamically loaded with javascript.. If i will use program like htttrack and make a mirror of that page. And then load the offline version which is mirrored in my computer it should work uhh, right?

Comment: I have no idea - never heard of `htttrack` so can offer no advice. Seems like a lot of extra work when there are potentially easier solutions available that do not rely upon you cloning a website/webpage....

Comment: Well **i** think that if I'll mirror about 2000 single page products which could take about 20 minutes, it should be faster than learning how to use "casper.js" etc.. Cause the src of that images has to be edited and then prepared for export to database. So i think in php and using simple html dom  it could be better. except that im not sure if that program "httrack" can mirror whole page with that loaded sliders. So  i think it will be  trial and error. Atleast thanks for response! <3